# App crash on huawaei device(Android 6.0 api 23)

Tags: android, performance

I try to debug my app on my device(with AVD no problem),in my MainActivity when the breakpoint is on this raw(with blue background) the Application crash:
[image: Raw of MainActivity]

This is my Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="rp.com.birthdayinfo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher3.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher3.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher3.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">
```

Finally is the logcat:

```
05-23 17:39:06.749 10940-10940/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@rp.com.birthdayinfo-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-23 17:39:07.042 10943-10943/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@rp.com.birthdayinfo-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-23 17:39:07.090 10945-10945/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@rp.com.birthdayinfo-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-23 17:39:07.139 10953-10953/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@rp.com.birthdayinfo-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-23 17:39:07.189 10961-10961/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@rp.com.birthdayinfo-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-23 17:39:07.241 10963-10963/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@rp.com.birthdayinfo-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-23 17:39:07.294 10966-10966/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@rp.com.birthdayinfo-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-23 17:39:07.358 10968-10968/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@rp.com.birthdayinfo-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-23 17:39:07.410 10970-10970/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@rp.com.birthdayinfo-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-23 17:39:07.466 10972-10972/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@rp.com.birthdayinfo-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-23 17:39:07.527 10974-10974/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@rp.com.birthdayinfo-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this is android manifests permission issue
Have u checked run time permission?
If not than read below link

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)